# OpenFileDialog utilizing Windows 10 Native Search

Tags: c#, winforms, search, openfiledialog

Once the OpenFileDialog has been displayed I would like to be able to use Windows 10 search index to narrow the list of files.  This would be the same as if you were in Windows Explore and typed into the search box, which is also shows up in the OpenFileDialog to the right.

From Jimi's comments I discovered that the only way to clear the search is by restoring the initial directory.  To do that you must use a environmental variable.  By doing this I now (still) have an issue.  When I type any character(s) in the search box no files are displayed.

I want to be able to open the dialog box, the go to the search box and type "Charles", for example, and list only those files with Charles in the name.

The revised code I use to open the dialog box is:

```
using(OpenFileDialog GetPhoto = new OpenFileDialog())
{
  GetPhoto.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures);
  GetPhoto.RestoreDirectory = true;
  GetPhoto.Filter = "All Files|*.*|All I 
            images|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;*.tif;*.bmp|JPEG Images|*.jpg|PNG 
            Images|*.png"; 
  GetPhoto.Multiselect = true;
  if (GetPhoto.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);`

Comment: You can store the last directory selected and set the `InitialDirectory` to the path of the first filename selected. Something like:  `if (ofd.FileName.Length > 0) { ofdLastDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(ofd.FileName); }`, where `ofd` is the OpenFileDialog instance and `ofdLastDir` is the Field that stores the path. -- You need to declare your OpenFileDialog with a `using` statement: `using (var ofd = new OpenFileDialog()) { ofd.InitialDirectory = ofdLastDir; ... }`.

Comment: Setting the InitialDirectory as you suggest did clear my last search a returned all files.  This worked without declaring in a using statement (which I have now done).  The main issue still reamains.  If I start typing "Charles" in the search box, no files show up in the directory.  I would also like to point out that all my photos are stored in the Public Pictures folders which I could not find in SpecialFolder.

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures);`

Comment: I have tried all the SpecialFolder variables.  That one just puts me in my Picture folder, not the pubic.  Currently working with GetPhoto.InitialDirectory = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%PUBLIC%").  I tried to set my own system variable but that didn't work.  Again, what I really need help with is using the search box.  Given the lack of response and posts is it even possible when using the openfiledialog box?  Because I need to select my folder every time using the dialog box filename doesn't work either.  Please provide me help with searching.  Thanks

Comment: You didn't follow the instructions very well. This path: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonPictures)` IS the `[Drive]:\Users\Public\Pictures` path. That's a virtual folder. The first time you open it, it will show all Images that are present in the Common path. Which includes the `Public` User and the current User's. When a File is selected, then the Path will be more *precise*, if you stored it as described.

Comment: Your Filter also needs to be setup correctly, e.g., `.Filter = "All Files|*.*|All Images|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif;*.tif;*.bmp|JPEG Images|*.jpg|PNG Images|*.png";` etc. Now, if you use the toolbar's Search box, when you reopen the Dialog - after you have set the `InitialDirectory` explicitly to the previous one (as described) - **and the Filter is correct**, the Search box won't be selected.

Comment: I originally did follow you instructions, but as you can see from my screen shot, that put me in my pictures folder.  All of my photos are in the public pictures folder and I needed to find something that would bring me close.  My entire issue is due to the limitation of setting the initialdirectory.  I need to change the list of files based off the name of the person in my catalog.  Ie; if the person is Charles, then only files with Charles in it.  Because I must always change folders, I can't keep the the filename.  I really appreciate you help with this and I have changed my filter also.

Comment: I don't understand.  85 views and 0 votes with no resolution.  Jimi I did everything you suggested and apparently have two issues: 1.  The SpecialFolder.CommonPictures is not pointed in the correct folder and 2.  I can't narrow the list of files.  How do I get help on this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had was not being able to set filename in my code to limit the list for a particular person.  Because I could not get a default folder set, when I changed folder the filename set from code was lost.  Thanks to me asking this question in a different way I was able to resolve the default folder issue and now don't need to use Windows 10 native search.

I guess the answer to this question is, you can't use native search from the OpenFileDialog Box.